# Memory Leak in JAVA/FLEX application

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-threads

After shut downing my application I get a memory leak error message :

```
<<Stopping Ebus Manager...
24-Oct-2023 14:36:22.840 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [gboxc_ccy] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.11/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.11/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:328)
 java.base@11.0.11/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:527)
 java.base@11.0.11/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
24-Oct-2023 14:36:22.855 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8110"]
24-Oct-2023 14:36:22.868 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8110"]
2023-10-24 14:36:27
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.11+9 mixed mode):

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00007f8d98001380, length=14, elements={
0x00007f8e34230000, 0x00007f8e34234000, 0x00007f8e3424d000, 0x00007f8e3424f000
}

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=1.08ms elapsed=84.79s tid=0x00007f8e34230000 nid=0xdad1b waiting on condition  [0x00007f8e14ffe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@11.0.11/Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@11.0.11/Reference.java:241)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@11.0.11/Reference.java:213)
```

I would like to analyze that problem ? From where do I start ?

Comment: Is this happening when Tomcat is stopping?

Comment: @aled yes only when the /bin/ . shutdown.sh is called

Comment: Then any potential memory leak is moot, since the process will end and release all memory.